# BLE GATT change peripheral device name and notify central

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to notify a bonded central that the device name of the peripheral has changed (on the fly)?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to any attribute are handled with Notifications or Indications.  However, not every attribute has a CCC value where you can turn on Notifications or Indications in order to be notified of a change.  I suspect most devices don't do this for the device name, but I suspect that most devices don't change names (ie. it's hard coded in).

So, best way to monitor the device name is set the CCC to get notifications.  But if there's no CCC value to set, then you have to poll the device to check for changes.